# $a_{n} \geq 0$ and $\sum a_{n} < \infty \implies \sum \frac{1}{n^{2}\cdot a_{n}}$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_{n}\geq 0$, and  $\sum a_{n}$ is convergent. Then how do I prove that

- $\displaystyle\sum\frac{1}{n^{2} \cdot a_{n}}$ is divergent.

I think if $\sum a_{n}$ converges the $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n}=0$.My intuition says that the quantity $n^{2}\cdot a_{n}$ should go to $0$ which will mean that it's reciprocal $\frac{1}{n^{2}\cdot a_{n}}$ will be large and hence $\sum \frac{1}{n^{2}\cdot a_{n}}$ will diverge. But I am unable to write a formal proof.

Comment: You may use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to derive a contradiction if both series are convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a way to solve from the first comment.  Here is another way.

If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum \dfrac{1}{n^2 a_n}$ are both convergent for $a_n \ge 0$, then:

$\sum \left( a_n + \dfrac{1}{n^2 a_n} \right)$ is convergent.  But $0  \le \dfrac{2}{n} \le a_n + \dfrac{1}{n^2 a_n}$ by AM-GM.  This implies the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is convergent, which presumably will give you a contradiction.

Comment: Simply superb! I love this answer.